# Let A ={x ∈ Z | x =18a − 2 for some integer a } and B ={y ∈ Z | y = 18b + 16 for some integer b} Prove A ⊆ B

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I'm fairly certain that this proposition is true, but I have no idea how to approach a proof for it.  I'm not looking for someone to do the work for me, I'm just trying to find out what type of proof I should use for this.

Comment: Let $x\in A$, then ..., then ..., hence $x\in B$. Therefore $A\subseteq B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** $$A=\{a \in \mathbb{Z} \: |\: 18a-2\}$$ and $$B=\{b \in \mathbb{Z} \: |\: 18b+16\}=\{b+1 \in \mathbb{Z} \: |\: 18(b+1)-2\}$$

What can you conclude about $a$ and $b$ from here?

Comment: @TK-421 Note that I posted this before Zelos' last two comments.

Comment: Note that that was unneccisary to state :)

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would write
$$A=18\mathbb{Z}-2$$
and
$$B=18\mathbb{Z}+16$$
at which it might become more evident what is going on

**Hint**:
Notice that infront of $\mathbb{Z}$ we have $18$ and then we substract/add some, do you see the difference between them and what it mounts to?

**Straight forward**:
The most straightforward manner to do it is just pick an element $a\in A$ show that it satesfies the construction of some element in $B$ and thereby proving it.

Comment: I was under the impression that using an example for a proof only works if it disproves the statement.

Comment: You cannot use a specific one like $16\in A$ to do it, you can however have $a\in A$ which means that there exists an $n$ such that $a=18n-2$, etc. When someone says "pick some element" it usually means "pick an arbitrary non-specific element that fits the definition" and because it's non-specific it is any element in the set and hence applies to all elements of the set.

Comment: Right, I understand that, but I don't get how to use "a is an arbitrary element in A", and then prove that it also exists in B.

Comment: $a=18n-2=18(n-1)+18-2=18(n-1)+16\in B$

Comment: did that help you?